# Multiple Pending Intent with different ID

Tags: java, android, android-pendingintent

i have a big problem with multiple pending intent, have different location, and fire only for the last. i try to change the unique id for every pendint intent but dont work. where is the error?

MainActivity.java

```
private void AddpromoAlert(){
    showpDialog();

    userDbHelper=new UserDbHelper(thiscontext);
    sqLiteDatabase=userDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor=userDbHelper.getMarker(sqLiteDatabase);

    if (cursor.getCount()!=0){

        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {
                String id,name, addr,  lati, longi;
                id = cursor.getString(0);
                name = cursor.getString(1);
                addr = cursor.getString(2);
                lati = cursor.getString(3);
                longi = cursor.getString(4);

                if(attivo.equalsIgnoreCase("si")){

                    if (promo.length() >= 5) {

                        Intent proximityIntent = new Intent (getContext(), ProximityActivity.class);

                        proximityIntent.putExtra("id", id);
                        proximityIntent.putExtra("desc", name);
                        proximityIntent.putExtra("addr", addr);
                        proximityIntent.putExtra("lati", lati);
                        proximityIntent.putExtra("longi", longi);

                        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getContext(), Integer.parseInt(id), proximityIntent,Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        locationManager.addProximityAlert(Double.parseDouble(lati), Double.parseDouble(longi), 30, -1, pendingIntent);



                    }
                }


            }while (cursor.moveToNext());

        }

    }

    userDbHelper.close();
    hidepDialog();
}
```

ProximityActivity.java

```
public class ProximityActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
String notificationTitle;
String notificationContent;
String tickerMessage;

PendingIntent pendingIntent;
String RicName,RicAddr,RicID;
Double latiRic,longiRic;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    boolean proximity_entering = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING, true);

    String RicName=getIntent().getExtras().getString("desc");
    String RicAddr=getIntent().getExtras().getString("addr");
    final double latiRic=getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("lati");
    final double longiRic=getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("longi");
    final String RicID=getIntent().getExtras().getString("id");

    if(proximity_entering)
    {
        notificationTitle="notification";
        notificationContent="Enter pov";
        tickerMessage = "alarm";
        SetNotification();
    }
    else
    {

    notificationTitle="notification'";
    notificationContent="leave pov";
    tickerMessage = "alarm";

    }


    finish();


}
public void SetNotification(){
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ViewMarkerPopup.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("content", notificationContent );
    notificationIntent.putExtra("desc", RicName);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("addr", RicAddr);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("lati", latiRic);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("longi", longiRic);



    notificationIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:/"+ (int)System.currentTimeMillis()));


    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), Integer.parseInt(RicID), notificationIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);


    NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setContentText(notificationContent)
            .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.centerlogo, 3)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setTicker(tickerMessage)

            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);


    long[] v = {500, 1000};
    notificationBuilder.setVibrate(v);




    Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();


    nManager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), notification);


    finish();
}
```

}

I'm looking for the solution for several weeks, tnx for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

In this call:

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getContext(),
   Integer.parseInt(id), proximityIntent,Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

remove `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and replace it with `0`. This is the `flags` argument and you should only be passing `PendingIntent` flags here, not `Intent` flags.

Comment: hi, seems work good, from logcat now i can see the enter and exit from other location, but now the problem is, except for the first activity load (at the start of app), fire multiple notification for the same object.

Comment: i think the problem is the accuracy of gps, but i can stop fire for a period of time if the already been notification?